# How to run a php script through batch file for windows 7?

Tags: php, batch-file

I have 2 php files. One which stores various xml files in a database and other php files takes those xml files as input, parse them and produces a another table having various information about the xml files.

I want this work to be scheduled for everynight.
**I want to do this via batch files but I have no idea how to use .bat files, and how to incoorporate the php script in it.**

Need help/guidance.

Thanks. 
Yogesh

Comment: use cron job no need for .bat files.

Comment: To clarify, what OS (Windows, Linux, something else) do you want to run them on?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are doing this on a windows machine as you mention a .bat file

PHP can be executed from a command line e.g. a dos shell

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php

Once you get it working manually just put what you are typing in a text file. (.bat)

You can execute the .bat file (a program file to windows) when you want using a scheduler, e.g. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/schedule-a-task

Answer (score 0):

1. create start.sh add this code:
   #!/bin/bash
   php /path/to/folder/script.php
2. chmod 644 script.php

OR

1. create start.sh add this code:
   #!/bin/bash
   /path/to/folder/script.php
2. chmod 755 script.php
3. the first line of your script.php has to be:
   #!/usr/bin/php

Comment: am using win7. Do you've any idea how to do this using .bat files ?? thanks

Comment: i guess it's the same, create your .bat and write: /path/to/php.exe /path/to/script.php

Comment: or add php.exe to your env_path and exec php /path/to/script.php from your .bat

Comment: thanks. I put my php path to enviornmental variable and used php -f path/tofile/file.php in batch file and scheduled it with task scheduler